# How to access td from controller in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried access to td of a table in controller.I want to change color of td by a condition in controller codes.I failed for access td from controller.How can I do ?

Index Partial

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
         <td id="istID" @ViewBag.istX  </td>
         <td> bla bla</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   //some codes
             if (status== "Online")
                    {
                        ViewBag.istX = "Online";
                        //change color td for blue
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.istX = "Offline";
                        //change color td for red
                    }
      }
```

Comment: I think it should be more like: `<td id="istID" class="@ViewBag.istX">  </td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this in view:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>

    @if(ViewBag.istX == "Online")
    {
    <td id="istID" style="background-color:green;">@ViewBag.istX</td>
    }
    else
    {
    <td style="background-color:red;">@ViewBag.istX</td>
    }
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

you can create a css class and apply that according to condition.

```
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>

        @if(ViewBag.istX == "Online")
        {
        <td id="istID" class="@ViewBag.istX">@ViewBag.istX</td>
        }
        else
        {
        <td class="@ViewBag.istX">@ViewBag.istX</td>
        }
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Solved by your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with variable style classes, that can be set from Controller, use:

```
<tr>
    <td id="istID" class="@ViewBag.istX">Test</td>
</tr>
```

Make sure you have a .css class named like the `istX` variable.
The style class could for example be:

```
.Online{
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

And

```
.Offline{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```